# Repeat specific action X number of times in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

So I want certain action to be performed X number of times, depends on how many times user wants it. User selection will be selected from a TextView string which is set up with this code:

```
    homeScreenPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dodajInterval();
            homeScreenMinus.setEnabled(counter > 0);
        }
    });

    homeScreenMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oduzmiInterval();
            homeScreenMinus.setEnabled(counter > 0);
        }
    });


}

private void oduzmiInterval() {
    counter--;
    brojIntervala.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
}

private void dodajInterval() {
    counter++;
    brojIntervala.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
}
```

Those are basicly two buttons that increment or decrement value of TextView.

The action I want to perform X times is this:

```
 public void homeScreenStart(View view) {
        linearniLayoutSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        new CountDownTimer(seekBarTimerDelay.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                countDownTimerTrci();

                karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
                textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_trci));
            }
        }.start();
    }


    private void countDownTimerTrci() {
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
        new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
                imageViewTimerSlika.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_niski_intenzitet);
                textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_hodaj));
                countDownTimerHodaj();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void countDownTimerHodaj(){
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
        new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliNiskogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText("Done!");
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

So it is combination of 3 seekbars, or timers, one running after another and then they should run as many times as user selects.

The problem is, I have no idea how to set this up, and I need that first block of code in timers to run just once, and those 2 methods below it to run X times.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something couldn't you just wrap your code in the action in a loop that references the current counter? You may need to block input so that the user can not modify the counter (unless you want them to) after execution has begun but that should be it.

```
public void homeScreenStart(View view) {
    linearniLayoutSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    CountDownTimer firstCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarTimerDelay.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
            countDownTimerTrci();

            karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
            textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_trci));
        }
    }

    CountDownTimer secondCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
            karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
            imageViewTimerSlika.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_niski_intenzitet);
            textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_hodaj));
            countDownTimerHodaj();
        }
    }

    CountDownTimer thirdCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
            karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
            imageViewTimerSlika.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_niski_intenzitet);
            textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_hodaj));
            countDownTimerHodaj();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        firstCountDown.start();
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
        secondCountDown.start();
        thirdCountDown.start();
    }
}
```

Should work for you

Comment: Well I can't add for loop below all that, just won't work

Comment: I didn't really examine the contents of your timers, simply make methods that ensure they run sequentially and you should be good to go. Otherwise even with your existing methodology they are going to step over each other.